# VBA/Access - Creating a New Table for each change in a field

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I am trying to write in VBA for Access.
I have a table with several members along with the vendors they belong to.
I want to write something that will create a new table at each change in vendor as to group all members with the same vendor into seperate tables but am new to VBA and not sure how to go about doing so.
for example:

```
Column 1  | Column 2
---------   ---------
Member 1  | Vendor 1;
Member 2  | Vendor 1;
Member 3  | Vendor 2;
Member 4  | Vendor 3;
```

I would like the following:

Table 1:

```
Member 1
Member 2
```

Table 2:

```
Member 3
```

Table 3:

```
Member 4
```

Any help that can be provided is very greatly appreciated.
I have tried searching Google for an answer but can't seem to find anything.
I know it would have to be some type of loop just not sure how to acheive this since I am not very familiar with VBA.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The relations between vendors and members is 1:1 or n:1. For example only 1 vendor for member, many vendors for 1 member or 1 vendor for many members?

Comment: 1 vendor for many members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I'm not sure exactly why you would want to do this...  that said, you never know.  Here is an example of a VBA function that would accomplish this:

```
Sub CreateTables()

  Dim rs As Recordset
  Dim sql As String
  Dim vendor As String

  sql = "select distinct [Vendor] from [Vendor Members]"

  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

  Do While Not rs.EOF
    vendor = rs!vendor

    sql = "select [Member] into [" & vendor & _
        "] from [Vendor Members] where [Vendor] = """ & vendor & """;"
    CurrentDb.Execute sql
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop


End Sub
```

This presupposes your table name is `Vendor Members`, but such things are easy enough to change on the fly.

Comment: This seems like it would work; however, I keep getting an error on the "Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset (sql). It says it's a syntax error in the FROM clause. Do you know why this might be happening? Again, this is my first time using VBA so I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Can you confirm the table names and such?  What is the exact name of your table and the fields within the table?  I kind of winged it in my example above, so I'm probably off.

Comment: The table is titled [GAP_REPORT_w_DRE-NEPH] I needed all the fields in the table so I just replaced [Members] with "*"

Comment: Ah, gotcha...  hopefully it's working now, then?  By the way, this  will only run once.  After that it's likely to give you an error saying the table already exists.  That's easy enough to remedy, should you need to.

Comment: I got it to work as I needed. Thank you so much @Hambone your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly are you trying to group the values by tables? You are not utilizing the full benefit of a relational database or for that matter, a database.

A simple query would definitely do:

`SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Column2 = 'Vendor 1'` would solve this if you are trying to get a result.

Comment: I am trying to group values by table so I can create separate Excel reports for each vendor.

Comment: @AlexJJimenez Again you can create a query and export the result set into excel sheet by worksheet/workbook

Comment: The table I am using has about 700 vendors. I believe if I were to use a query I would have to create a Make Table query for each vendor and then extract each table to Excel. Using Hambone's VBA I was able to create each separate table and I was able to write script to export all tables into separate Excel files at once. If you can specify how a single query can accomplish this I am more than willing to give it a try. I am using Access since it is the only program available that I feel can accomplish this task. I do not really need a database for its intented use.